# Count Unique Combination of Values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine the following scenario:

```
ColA | ColB
1    | 1
1    | 2
1    | 3
2    | 1
2    | 2
2    | 3
3    | 1
3    | 2
3    | 3
```

Using SQL Server 2008, how would I count an occurrence such that the combination (1,2) would be the same as (2,1) and therefore my results would be as follows:

```
ColA | ColB | Count
1    | 1    | 1
1    | 2    | 2
1    | 3    | 2
2    | 2    | 1
2    | 3    | 2
3    | 3    | 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select 
 ColA,
 ColB, 
 case when ColA < ColB then ColA else ColB end as ColC, 
 case when ColA > ColB then ColA else ColB end as ColD
from yourtable)
select 
ColC as ColA,
ColD as ColB,
count(1) as Count
from cte
group by ColC, ColD
order by ColC, ColD
```

Answer (score 1):

Before grouping, normalize the data by making `Col1 = MIN(Col1, Col2)` and `Col2 = MAX(Col1, Col2)`. This converts each possible combination to a canonical one. Then, do the usual grouping.

Answer (score 0):

An Example has be posted just before mine but i though i would post anyhow.

replace YourTable with the table you are going to query the data from and this below solution will work.

it joins 2 sets of data together in the WITH clause and then selects the 2 columns and does the count.

```
WITH data as (
    select 
          ColA
         ,ColB
    from YourTable
union all
    select 
          ColA
         ,ColB
    from YourTable 
    where ColB <> ColA and ColA <> ColB
) 
select 
     ColA
    ,ColB
    ,count(*) as [Count]
from data
GROUP BY ColA,ColB
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select (case when colA < colB then colA else colB end) as ColA,
       (case when colA < colB then colB else colA end) as ColB,
       count(*)
from table t
group by (case when colA < colB then colA else colB end),
         (case when colA < colB then colB else colA end);
```

This would look simpler if SQL Server supported `greatest()` and `least()` as some other databases do.  But the `case` statement works just as well.